# XCode, проблема подключения фреймворка

Tags: xcode, swift

Решил протестить SwiftyJson+Alamofire, но так как я начинающий в ИОСе, то не знаю в чем проблема. Вроде установил все, как "книжка пишет". Подключил 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то при наборе первых слов на коннект пишет вот это 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно пускать на дальнейшую работу типа этого

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.example.com")
.responseString { response in
    print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
```

В интернетах решения не нашел. и такая же проблема со SwiftyJson, дальше не пускает, видно туплю, но где не знаю)

Comment: Подскажи решилось как то ? Такая же проблема

Comment: Решилось, но я уже не помню как, попробуй скопипастить цельный блок со всеми скобками , а не обращаться и не углубляться через точку .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу, ты установил через Pods. Есть вероятность, может что упустил, поэтому постараюсь объяснить с нуля как подрубать либы через `cocoaPods`: 
Открой терминал и пропиши `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Затем когда все установится там же в терминале прописываешь путь к своему проекту следующим образом:

```
cd yourPath/...
```

когда путь прописал в терминале пропиши:

```
pod init
```

система должна создать тебе `PodFile`. Открой этот подфайл и пропиши либы которые тебе нужны, на гитхабе в описании той или иной либы есть строка который нужно прописать в `PodFile` например:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘9.0’
use_frameworks!

target ‘YourApp’ do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.3'
end
```

после этого сохрани `command+s` можешь закрыть подфайл и в терминале прописать `pod isntall` (не забывай про путь. Путь должны быть твоего проекта). Система сама "прикрутит" либы к твоему проекту, а в директории проекта у тебя должен появиться файл твоего проекта с расширением `xcworkspace`, например `YourApp.xcworkspace`. В дальнейшем будешь работать с проектом через этот файл.

В классе где тебе нужен Alamofire делаешь импорт `import Alamofire` и все само должно дописывать. Можешь и пробилдить проект  на всякий случай: `command+B`

Comment: Спасибо, но я так и делал, уже пару раз), Сам фреймворк в проэкте вроде есть, если делается import Alamofire, но автозаполнения нету, просто одна команда AlamofireVersionNumber. 

К Post или Get методам даже не подобраться

Answer (score 0):

Если версия **Alamofire** *5+*, то необходимо использовать класс **AF** вместо **Alamofire**.